# How to highlight the color for non english search keyword as orange in pdfclown

Tags: java, pdfclown

I am using pdf clown and  i got the requirement like  highlight  the color for  non english search keyword as orange.Currently i am able to search the keyword and highlight with yellow color for non english keywords  as per the screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Kindly provide your inputs to highlight  the color for  non english search keyword as orange.Thanks in advance .

Comment: The highlight colour does not depend on the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I assume your code is the same as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48395771/1729265) with PDF Clown fixed as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48585527/1729265).*

In the code the highlight annotation is created without any color selection. Thus, yellow is used.

If you add a color selection to

```
new TextMarkup(page, highlightQuads, null, MarkupTypeEnum.Highlight);
```

like this

```
new TextMarkup(page, highlightQuads, null, MarkupTypeEnum.Highlight).withColor(new DeviceRGBColor(1, .5, .2));
```

you get

[image: screenshot with orange highlight]

Comment: @mkl-Thanks you so much.